# Is there a version of jquery UI that works with jQuery 1.4.2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://skfox.com/2010/01/14/jquery-ui-1-7-2-not-ready-for-jquery-1-4/

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/common-problem-jquery-ui-and-jquery-1-4-x

They all met problem when using jquery ui with jQuery 1.4,is there a release of jquery UI that's compatible with jquery 1.4 now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, jQuery UI 1.8+ (as of this question: 1.8.6) [you can download it from the main site](http://jqueryui.com/download).